# Azure Self Hosted Agent - How to know when to upadte version?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

I am working with Azure DevOps Services on Self Hosted Agents.

Recently The Agent Stopped Working after more than 4 months.

Everything was looking ok when checking the Agents Page.
[image]
All Pipeline were Queued, but no Agent was busy all was idle
After Checking and rebooting agent i checked version of downloaded agent
[image]

And Then Updated to new agent version manually - and problem was solved.

1. Any way to get notified when i must update agent version?
2. Auto Update Didn't work - is there a place where i can view the log of the update?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For updating self-hosted agent, here is an [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#agent-version-and-upgrades) for your reference:

[image]

Then if you would like to see log of the update, please kindly go to your local, your self-hosted agent folder->diag, you should be able to see something like this:

[image]

Hope it could do some help.

Comment: no option to get notification for obsolete agent version  ?

Comment: Hi @galsi, since an upgrade is requested when a platform feature or one of the tasks used in the pipeline requires a newer version of the agent. There is no option now to get notification for obsolete agent version. We suggest setting automatically update for your self-hosted agent to run the newer version tasks. And if you need specific version for running old project with old tasks, you could go to Github and search and download the specific version: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/releases?q=2.213.1&expanded=true. Thanks.